# Multi dimensional array value with SELECT BETWEEN - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

Hi basically my aim is to get total weight count and its sum form specific range , like :

**0.1 to 0.5**  or **0.6 - 1.0** or **1.01 - 1.50** .... so on on...

Hence for each range i have to write separate select query ? like below :

```
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 0.1 AND 0.5
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 0.6 AND 1.0
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 1.01 AND 1.5
```

It may have many range like above its not fixed.

**Hence result i want is as below :**

```
0.1 - 0.5    = 3 / 9.4   - ( its total count / sum of weight )
0.6 - 1.0    = 2 / 4.5
1.01 - 1.5   = 0 / 0

... so on and on....
```

Hence i taught to keep that range in an multidimensional array and pass to select query in for loop / for each as below :

```
$info = array("0" =>array("a1"=>0.1,"a2"=>0.5),
              "1" => array("b1"=>0.6,"b2"=>1.0),
              "2" => array("c1"=>1.01,"c2"=>1.5),
              "3" => array("d1"=>1.51,"d2"=>2.0)
             );


echo"<table>";
 foreach($info as $row) {
  echo('<tr>');
  foreach($row as $cell) {
    echo('<td>' . $cell . '</td>');

   $sql = "SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN ".$cell." and ??????";

  }
  echo('</tr>');
} 
echo "</table>";
```

AS ITS taking each single value in SELECT value , when i echo sql select i see 8 times select query , where as i should get only 4 select query as per ranges

how i can work out with BETWEEN

IF ANY OTHER SUGGESTION TO GET BELOW RESULT PLEASE LET ME KNOW :

```
0.1 - 0.5    = 3 / 9.4   - ( its total count / sum of weight )
0.6 - 1.0    = 2 / 4.5
1.01 - 1.5   = 0 / 0

... so on and on....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting your foreach:

```
echo"<table>";
foreach($info as $row) {
    echo('<tr>');
    echo "<td>SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN ".implode(' and ', $row) . "</td>";
    echo('</tr>');
}
echo "</table>";
```

`implode` will combine the elements of the array into a string with the word `and` between each array element.

For example:

```
array("a1"=>0.1,"a2"=>0.5)
```

becomes:

```
0.1 and 0.5
```

The above output is:

```
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 0.1 and 0.5
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 0.6 and 1
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 1.01 and 1.5
SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN 1.51 and 2
```

Comment: hi richard , thanks , i tried as you said , but result i got as " SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN "  and that to 8 time  - SELECT count(*),sum(wght) FROM PROD WHERE wght BETWEEN

Comment: i think implode is not working , also i should get SELECT QUERY ONLY 4, but i am getting 8 times select query in loop

Comment: hi richard can you help me

Comment: Fixed answer. I had put the implode in the wrong `foreach`.

Comment: thanks :) ... but can i get result as ....  0.1 - 0.5    = 3 / 9.4   - ( its total count / sum of weight )  ??? ... because i m not getting - in between 0.1 0.5

Comment: solution above is only for  3 / 9.4 as per select query ... but 0.1 - 0.5 is missing ... i got that to soultion what i did for-each in for-each .. in one td i have call 0.1 0.5 thats cell variable foreach of mine which i did above  and in another td u r foreach  select query above .. but 0.1 0.5 is coming but widout " - " i need  0.1 - 0.5 = 3 / 9.4 but i am getting  0.1  0.5 = 3 / 9.4  .. need - in between 0.1 0.5

Comment: You just want to show the range before the query? Just do another `td` with `implode`. Something like : `<td><?php echo implode(' - ', $row);?></td>`